# Android, set new root activity

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to set new root activity, **min SDK 16, compile/target SDK 24, testing on Nexus 6 API 23 Emulator**, here is the scenario:

Activity A is the main Activity, defined as action = `android.intent.action.MAIN` and category = `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` at the Manifest.

From **Activity A** I move to registration activity(**Activity B**), when I'm done I move to **Activity C**, now for **Activity C** at the Manifest I added `android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"` and `android:noHistory="true"` when I move from **Activity B** to **Activity C** I use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityB.this, ActivityC.class);
                     // Btw I did try addFlags
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
```

**The problem:** for some reason when I hit the back button at **Activity C** I return to **Activity A**, I want the app to exit, I that after the registration(**Activity B**) ends the new root activity will be **Activity C**.

**Solution:**

Within **Activity C** I override onBackPressed and within the overriding method I call:

```
moveTaskToBack(true);
```

**Note:** don't call `super.onBackPressed()`, it will back to **Activity A** and then move the task to back(moveTaskToBack), so when you relaunch the app it will call **Activity A** `onResume` and not `onCreate`, in my case the redirection was made within `onCreate` so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution I did to mimic this was by overriding backpress, so that my users couldn't jump back.  Similarly you could close the app on backpress click by overriding it and exiting app.

Comment: I did try this way, hopped for more elegant way but couldn't find one, thanks(I will edit my question with the code).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityB.this, ActivityC.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
startActivity(intent);
```

Also, if you are calling this code from within ActivityB, you can just use the keyword `this`.

EDIT: please look at the flags I'm using, I don't believe your using the right ones.

Comment: Logan, if you take a look at my question I did try this and it didn't work